# How can I write generic react component wrappers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have a set of functional components that use a common set of properties, for ex:

```
const A = ({ x, y, z }) = {...}
const B = ({ x, y, z }) = {...}
```

I have partially fixed configurations for these components:

```
const styles {
    A: {
        type1: {
            x: 1,
            y: "something",
        },
    },
    B: {
        type1: {
            x: 2,
            y: "else",
        },
    },
};
```

To use these configurations, I've been writing a fixed component for each one:

```
// i have SFCs for A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2, ... etc.
const A1 = (props) = {
    return <A x={styles.A.type1.x} y={styles.A.type1.y} {...props} />
}

...

// inside my business logic component
return (
    <A1 z="state" />
)
```

This has been ok for a small amount of components and partial prop sets. However, going forward I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
type A1 = styledType(styles.A.type1)(A);
return <A1 z="some_state" />
```

Do I need to define `styledType` in a type script file? Is mixing TS with JSX in a default `create-react-app` code base OK?

Can I refer to types (without instances) in JSX? Is what I just wrote above valid?

If there is something that already does this (react or even just plain JS / JSX / TS / whatever), I'm all ears!

So far this is what I've been playing with this:

```
const styledTyped = (styles) => {
    return (component: C) => <C {...styles} />; // ????
};

export default styledTyped;
```

I know I need to return a callable that takes a component type, and returns a type wrapper that would have those properties injected.

I have no idea how to do that though... I'm currently studying material UI's `withStyles`, but it's got a lot going on and is a bit hard to follow as someone without experience in these languages.

---

EDIT:

I've gotten closer after looking at the implementation of `withStyles` in `@material-ui/styles/withStyles/withStyles.js`. I have something like this:

```
const withElementStyles = (styleProps) => {
  return (Component) => {
    return (props) => {
      const newElement = React.createElement(Component, { ...props, ...styleProps });
      return newElement;
    };
  };
};
```

This is almost working. It does indeed create the component with the fixed properties, as well as the ones I pass to the wrapper. However, I seem to have lost `instance.type.name` attribute, something I was relying on to perform type based dispatch of a few function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution (after learning about defaultProps), but also had to adjust other code (for the better).

I now have this:

```
const withStyledElement = (fixedProps) => {
  return (Component) => {
    const StyledElement = (props) => {
      return <Component {...props} />;
    };
    StyledElement.defaultProps = fixedProps;
    StyledElement.displayName = Component.name;
    StyledElement.getConnector = Component.getConnector; // see below
    return StyledElement;
  };
};
```

I mentioned above that I was using the component name to perform type dispatch. This failed when I used a wrapped component like:

```
const WrappedA = withElementStyles(styles.A.1)(A);
```

because the component name is "StyledElement".

I decided that relying on the name was not a good approach. At the time I didn't realize you could bind functions to components after defining them.

So instead of dispatching on name, I use an expected bound method:

```
const getConnector = (instance, arg) => {
    return instance.getConnector(instance, arg);
}
```

Now I don't have to add cases for each type, and I can create one-liner wrapped components that for all the flavors I need.